# How delete irrelevant rows from dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Imagine that in column S1 an event, and in column RES its result. How can I leave in the data frame only the last result of each event?

Source data frame:

```
S1      RES DATE
red     1   01.01.2019
red     2   02.01.2019
red     1   03.01.2019
red     22  04.01.2019
green   1   05.01.2019
green   4   06.01.2019
black   1   07.01.2019
black   0   08.01.2019
black   1   09.01.2019
```

Required data frame:

```
S1      RES DATE
red     22  04.01.2019
green   4   06.01.2019
black   1   09.01.2019
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: so simple, thanks!

Comment: make sure that your dataframe is ordered by date, before applying df.drop_duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['S1'], keep='last')